# Domain of function of form $f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{k(x)}$

Tags: calculus, functions

I just want to know did we have a rule to find the domain of function in form of $f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{k(x)}$ .I know $k(x)\ne 0$ . but in general do we have any rule to compute domain of function like that. thanks

Comment: $k(x)\ne 0$ and the domains of both $g(x)$ and $k(x)$.

Comment: I think you want to say  is $D_f= D_g \cap (D_k - \{x|k(x)=0\})$ and this what I think. but I am not sure why I do not see this rule in any book( that I read before now ).